# How to set limit to maximum task for HttpClient

Tags: c#, task, httpclient

I am receiving "429 Too Many Request" when sending multiple requests to a website. I would like to be able to send multiple requests to get response from the URL with a limit or run the task as a batch so that I don't receive the error from the website.

Below is the code I tired. It works fine but after sending a handful of requests it gives the too many request message.

```
const int maxConcurrency = 15;
try
{
    List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> taskList = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
    List<string> replies = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lbURLToSearch.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        taskList.Add(reusableHTTPClient.GetAsync(lbURLToSearch.Items[i].ToString()));
        if (taskList.Count >= maxConcurrency)
            Task.WaitAny(taskList.ToArray());
    }

    var httpClientResponse = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    foreach (var htmlContent in httpClientResponse)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await htmlContent.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
            //replies.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(reader.ReadToEnd()));
            rawHTMLFromSource += await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }

    foreach (var reply in replies)
    {
        // TODO:        
    }
}
catch
{

}
```

What can I do to reduce the number of requests?

Comment: Depending on the website, it may not be number of concurrent requests that is the limiting factor, it may be the number of requests per unit of time. You should probably check with the owners of the site to find out what their limits are...

Comment: you need some how to get response status before continue looping like this. This code is kind of ddos attack, you might risk your ISP block your internet line. of course with out having in depth knowledge about your goal to this question.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ - not using this to ddos any site. which is why i need it to send the job as a batch so and wait until the batch job is done so that it does not ddos the site.